# Can you suggest class structure for well known Mars rover application

Tags: php, class, object-oriented-analysis

I hope many of you might have heard about well knows "mars rover problem" if not then please check here http://thefundoowriter.com/2009/10/01/the-mars-rover-problem/ I am working on this but I am not that much expert in classes and objects, I have made this program in procedural php its working fine but I am confused about class,object based solution.

What classes and methods should be there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you procedural program is already working you can use it as a base and make it OOP. Have a look at your procedures. Which procedures use similar parameters? Those group of parameters might be a good start for a class and  the procedures for the methods.

Comment: Thank alex, Actually i have rough design in mind. But still i am looking for a better class design :(

Comment: You could post your class design and ask for improvements.

Comment: this is what i have in my mind right now
 class plateau 
 1) function set_plateau_dimentions()
 2) function is_rover_inside_plateau()

 class movements extends plateau
 1) function spinleft()
 2) function spinright()
 3) function move()

 class rover extends movements
 1) function rover_actions() 
 2) function set_initial_position()
 3) function get_rover_position()

Comment: one suggestion: You do not have to repeat the class name in the function. Just setDimensions instead of set_plateau_dimensions

Comment: thanks alex...i will be posting my code after coading...so u guys can suggest modifications.

Comment: Would be nice if you upvote my answer and comments :-)